# ExpressJS + MongoDB: Better to make one API call with 10,000 objects, or 10,000 individual API calls?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, optimization

I'm building an app that relies on a web scraper built in Node/Express, which operating on the same localhost as my front-facing Node/Express app.

I'm trying to optimise as much as possible and I'm completely new to all of this so please forgive if it's a basic question. Let's use this flow as an example:

1. The front-facing app generates a list of about 10,000 domain names
2. The front-facing app sends this data to my scraping app's api
3. The scraper app does its magic then saves a whole lotta data to MongoDB

In terms of optimisation and best practice, is it better if my front-facing app sends one request to the scraper API per domain name? Or is it better to send an array of 10,000 strings to the scraper in one `POST` and parse through it within the app itself?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the question linked to.  The linked question talks about monitoring and tooling for load/capacity planning.  This question is about *application optimization*.

Comment: @Mendhak: The direction is the same: We can't tell what's the best approach in the OPs specific case. He has to test what performs best in his case.

Comment: We can tell, actually - in this case it would be better to chunk the requests together due to the overhead of opening/closing a connection (do many at once).  The linked thread talks of capacity planning, load testing (heavy traffic).  They aren't at all the same.